# Best practice for branching a branch and combining with trunk in SVN?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

I was just wondering what the best practice would be in this scenario:

I have "Branch A" which was branched a month ago or so off of the trunk which contains unfinished code. I also have code which is currently at the head of the trunk.

What I need is to be able to have another branch which contains both the current code on the trunk and the code in "Branch A", but I want to rename it to "Branch B". The new branch is supposed to be for working on features for a specific release down the road, whereas "Branch A" was just for working on a specific feature.

Do I:

A) Merge from the trunk to the branch and then rename the branch?

B) Make a branch from the trunk and then merge "Branch A" into the newly created "Branch B"?

C) Do a "two way merge" in TortoiseSVN?

D) Some other option?

Was just wondering what would be recommended in this case, and what would give the least headaches down the road.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always a good idea to keep your branches up to date with changes from trunk. So, for your scenario, I would first merge trunk changes into branch A. Then, I would create a branch B from Branch A.

After both branches have been created, I would do my best to merge trunk changes into both Branch A and B as the changes to trunk occur.

Comment: All work being done in A is now going to be done in B. Should I delete Branch A or something after B is created? I guess I can't if I branch B from A.

Comment: If the point of branch B is to get rid of branch A, then you should just merge trunk changes into branch A and then you are done. Branch B would never need to be created. It sounded like you had the need for 2 branches in your original question.

Comment: Well, I need to integrate the changes from branch A first. I just want it called "branch B" and have it contain both the current code from the trunk head as well as the changes from "branch A".

Answer (score 2):

There is obvisouly some workflow that will lead to a lot of headhaches.

I came accross the same question and found this article very interesting
[Bunny Hop](http://designbygravity.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/what-mother-never-told-you-about-svn-branching-and-merging/)

Comment: That's genius. It's essentially option B, in my case, isn't it?

Comment: How does this work with SVN >= 1.5 though with merge tracking?

Comment: check http://designbygravity.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/what-mother-never-told-you-about-svn-branching-and-merging/#comment-1241

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend B option. It is important to keep chronological order of your branches. Changes from older branches should be merged to newer ones. In that way you can avoid cross merging conflicts. So I would create a new branch from head (branch B). Then I would merge in that order:
branch A -> branch B -> head